# Protecting vias with plated copper with the toner transfer method

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, via, etching

With the film photoresist method, the film, if not etched off, can be used to form a protective layer over via to prevent the copper inside from being etched.

Is this possible with the toner transfer method,  without plugging up the via manually?

Comment: Can't you just drill the via holes _after_ etching?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I could, but I'm trying to doing two layer PCBs, which requires connections between layers.

Comment: You can print gerbers with filled holes is that's what you want. But then you can't drill them without damaging the annular ring. Are you going to plate copper in the via?

Comment: @Jeroen3 Yes, I plant to drill and plate before etching

Comment: Vias may be protected by the photoresist film building "tents" over the plated drill holes. I doubt building of "tents" is possible using the toner transfer method. The tent material needs some stability to protect the hole.